# Is gravity reversed during inflation?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I am not clear on that.

Is gravity repulsive during inflation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is very difficult to answer, and in the end, the answer is going to be more semantic than it's going to be physcial.  The reason for this is that it's very difficult to pull apart what is done by "gravity" and what is done by the matter content of the universe.

The safest answer to this is to say that during inflation, the matter content of the universe has a predominantly negative pressure, which causes objects to expand.  During a truly inflationary period, the density of this substance doesn't decrease as the universe expands, so the rate of expansion is approximately exponential.  There are various ways to create a scenario like this if you assume different properties for the quantum field theoretic vacuum or various types of matter coupled to gravity.